# Increasing value of variable via button in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to increase variable value, but I get this error:

> "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment"

Can someone help me please?

.kv:

```
<InputValuesScr>:
    GridLayout:
        rows:2
        TextInput:
            input_filter: 'float'
            font_size: 50
            text: 'Please, input value of x1'
            id: xval
            multiline: False
            on_touch_down: self.text = ''
        Button:
            text: 'Submit'
            on_press: root.x_changer()
```

.py:

```
global x
x = 1

class TypeOfGeometryScr(Screen):
    pass

class SelectDemensionsScr(Screen):

    def submit_dn(self):
        global dn
        dn = self.ids.demensions.text

class InputValuesScr(Screen):

    def x_changer(self):
        x = x
        x += 1
        self.ids.xval.text = 'Please, input value of x' + str(x)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your error message is about *local* variable `x`, and in your code you've defined a global `x` **and** a local `x`. Python requires you to specify that a variable is meant to reference the global one if you use it within a function. Is that what you meant to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening becouse the `global x` is in the global scope and not in the `x_changer()` function lac scope. For solve this u need to move the `global x` inside the local scope of the function

```
def x_changer(self):
        global x
        x = x
        x += 1
        self.ids.xval.text = 'Please, input value of x' + str(x)
```

Comment: Thank you, very much <3

Comment: if it is the answer that you was searching consider to accepting the answer :)